# Docker error response from daemon on Mac M1 processor - unexpected EOF

Tags: docker, apple-m1, macbookpro

I'm using a Macbook with M1 apple silicon processor and Docker. It seems that Docker is having issues because of the different architecture of the Mac processor.

Every time I try to run any docker command I get similar errors as the one below.

Example:

```
docker login ...
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unexpected EOF
```

I've tried to reinstall and re-login multiple times, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any clues?

Comment: Our leading hypothesis now is that if you have a special character in the home folder you run into this problem in my case my home folder is an email "foo@bar.com" the @ is the problem

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm also experiencing it

Comment: Yes, answered as an answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was the `@` at my mac username as we were using emails for login. I had to create a new user without any special characters in the name, then the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, it might work for you:

### Note 1: System and Docker Setup

**Update Your Operating System:** Ensure that your macOS is up to date by installing the latest updates.

**Update Docker**: Make sure you are using the latest version of Docker.

**Configure Docker Settings**:

- Open Docker.
- Navigate to `Settings`.
- Under `General`, select the `VirtioFS` option.
- Under Feature in development, check only `Use containerd for pulling and storing images`.

### **Note 2**: Troubleshooting Container Issues

If you encounter issues when starting containers, follow these steps:

**Docker Resource Adjustment**:

- Open Docker.
- Go to `Settings`.
- Navigate to `Resources`.
- Increase the allocated resources as needed to meet your container requirements.

**Avoid using images with AMD64 alerts**: Try to only pull and use images without AMD64 alert, otherwise it will most probably fail to start.

### Note 3: Applying Changes

Remember to apply any changes you make in Docker settings by clicking the `Apply & restart` button. This ensures that your configurations take effect.

In case you still have issues after applying changes, try restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was solved by downgrading docker desktop on my corporate M1 Mac as others indicated here: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6704